# How do I update my iPhone 5 ios?

Tags: ios

I can't download apps from the AppStore with my iPhone 5. I keep getting a pop-up message; "this app needs ios 6". How do I update my ios?

Answer (score 1):

From the **Settings** on your **iPhone 5** you can check for updates:

- Select **Settings** [The app that looks like gears]
- Tap **General**
- Tap **Software Update** and follow the instructions.

Alternatively, and preferably, you should use **iTunes** on your Mac or PC to first back up your iPhone then install the updates.

- Plug your iPhone into your Mac or PC using the USB Cable that came with your iPhone.  This is the cable you use to charge your iPhone with.
- Follow the instructions presented in **iTunes.**