# Unable to update apps

Tags: ios-appstore

I am unable to update any of my apps on my iPhone 5 and can not add a new app. When I try to update I get a spinning circle. There has been no error notice. Any idea what is my problem?

Comment: Are you connecting through cellular or wifi services?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your iPhone to the latest version.  The **iPhone 5** shipped with **iOS 6** installed.  To check your current version, go to:

- **Settings**
- **General**
- **About**
- scroll down to **Version**

To update select **Software Update**.  See [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193459/120171) for more information or go to [Apple's Support website.](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone/)